# Is it possible to upload with torrent?

Tags: website, bittorrent, upload

I'm looking for a website that allow me to upload a file using torrent technology instead of http/ftp as we usually see.

Do you know if it exists?

I tried to find one, but I could only find websites that allow me to upload files via http/ftp or torrent files via http, and not file via torrent.

*Edit to put the answer here:*
In fact Dropbox (and similar services) are doing exactly what I want.

Comment: The power of torrents comes from multiple people holding the same file and you can take a piece here, a piece there. Reverse the situation. You're a single person with a file. They can only download from one person at a time, not in pieces... So there would be no advantage, it might actually be slower, than just using HTTP

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to send a big file to someone, but we aren't connected at the same moment so P2P between us won't be possible, this is why I'm looking for a website where I could upload the file. Another problem is that my internet connection isn't steady so ftp/http upload fail or the file get corrupted.

Comment: This is exactly what ftp or dropbox is for.

Comment: If your connection stinks too much to upload via `ftp`, then [dropbox](http://dropbox.com) is a great resource.  Another option is to break your file into multiple archives using either `7zip` or `WinRar` and upload sequentially.

Comment: Ho crap I didn't thought about dropbox, thanks my problem is solved so :D

Comment: Nobody should be using FTP at this point unless they are in a corporate ecosystem with some very peculiar restraints. SFTP or SCP have been around for ages and are superior in pretty much every way. HTTP upload/download resume is not commonly implemented, but most SFTP clients and servers support resumed transfers. Your other best option is to use a multipart archive so you can upload/send one piece at a time. Dropbox is also pretty convenient (though you have to pay for extra  storage if the file is very large).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't *upload* a file using Bittorrent.  You *distribute* it.

To distribute it, you need to:

- Select a tracker or two for the torrent
- Use any "create torrent" function in your software to make the torrent, referencing the file you want to distribute.
- Open this torrent in your own torrent software.  You'll see it says 100%.  This is what you want.  You are seeding the file for others.
- Upload the `.torrent` file to the tracker or torrent site of your choice, or hand it out to others.
- Keep seeding the file until you see the ratio is above 1.  When the ration is above 1, there is a complete copy of the file "out there"
- Seed longer to keep the torrent alive longer.

If you only have to give the file to one other person, Dropbox as mentioned in the comments may be better, unless you want to leave the torrent running.  BitTorrent really shines when it's a one-to-many distribution relationship.